# How much would Jupiter heat up if you accelerate Jupiter out of orbit around the sun using fusion candles?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocketry, radiation

So, I responded to a post of someone saying that you could turn Jupiter into a spaceship using fusion candles. I mentioned that doing so would dramatically heat up the planet, especially if you were to accelerate it out of orbit of the sun over the course of decades, even centuries if needed. Someone else jumped in and claimed that the black body radiation of the planet would keep the temperature nominal. Furthermore the time period of acceleration applied would not be a significant factor because the temperature of the planet would reach "equilibrium". I thought this was absurd considering the amount of energy required to accelerate Jupiter with this method, as it was claimed these candles would be fusing hydrogen and helium of the atmosphere of Jupiter and blasting the resulting fusion plasma down on the planet at .5c to provide the acceleration. And while of course there would likely be some max temperature Jupiter would reach where the amount of thermal radiation would be equal to the amount these candles add to Jupiter, that temperature would be quite significant. Much much higher than the current temperature of the planet.

I need everyone's help to settle the debate. Maths/Calculation would be greatly appreciated! (here is a website I found that covers the basic idea: https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/6036af70d08fd)

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on SE Physic than SE Engineering.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better on Physic SE

Comment: I already posted it to SE Physics and they booted me over here.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706237/how-much-would-jupiter-heat-up-if-you-accelerate-jupiter-out-of-orbit-around-the

Comment: "This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see this meta post.

Closed yesterday.

(Private feedback for you)"

Comment: calculate the energy required to move the planet.  Then compare that energy to the mass of the planet and calculate the temperture change.  Go.